flutter_sound exceptions when disposing audio player/recorder (in debug mode only)
I am having issues closing the audio sessions. The program is stalling when await _mPlayer!.closePlayer()... is run. I am trying to cleanly dispose of all of the flutter sound related objects in the file. Google docs link to the file
@override
  void dispose() {
    _descriptionController.removeListener(() {});
    _descriptionController.dispose();
    _videoController?.dispose();

    _closePlayerAndRecorder();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _closePlayerAndRecorder() async {
    try {
      if (_mPlayer != null) {
        print('Closing player session...');
        await _mPlayer!.closePlayer().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));
        _mPlayer = null;
        print('Player session closed.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Exception when closing player session: $e');
    }

    try {
      if (_mRecorder != null) {
        print('Closing recorder session...');
        await _mRecorder!.closeRecorder().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));
        _mRecorder = null;
        print('Recorder session closed.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Exception when closing recorder session: $e');
    }
  }

I've tried running it without the await in front of close player and recorder:
@override
  void dispose() {
    _mPlayer!.closePlayer();
    _mPlayer = null;

    _mRecorder!.closeRecorder();
    _mRecorder = null;
    super.dispose();
  }

The audio players successfully close according to the console output, but it hits the exception on super.dispose(). This is the call stack I get when it hits super.dispose():
call stack
I should add that I have tried disabling breakpoints at exceptions (including uncaught ones), and it works as intended, but I know that isn't a good practice.
